How can I prevent dynamic folders in Google Cloud Document AI Workflow?
I'm encountering issues with Google Cloud Document AI workflow where the processed JSON output files are being saved in dynamically generated folders. For instance, after processing a file, the JSON output is saved in a path like gs://my-output-bucket/dynamic-folder1/dynamic-folder2/processed-file.json. These dynamic folder names change with each run, making it difficult to programmatically locate and access the processed JSON files. How can I configure the Document AI workflow to save the processed JSON files directly in a specified folder or make it easier to programmatically locate them?
I tried configuring my Google Cloud Document AI workflow to save processed JSON files in a consistent, non-dynamic folder structure. Despite setting the outputConfig parameter to a specific path, the files still end up in dynamically named subfolders, making it difficult for my Streamlit app to locate and process them. I expected the JSON files to be saved directly in the specified output folder without additional dynamic subfolders.
Here's my current workflow:
main:
params: [input]
steps:
- start:
call: sys.log
args:
text: ${input}
- vars:
assign:
- input_gcs_bucket: ${input.inputBucket}
- output_gcs_bucket: ${input.outputBucket}
- processor_id: ${input.processorId}
- location: ${input.location}
- project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
- batch_process:
call: googleapis.documentai.v1.projects.locations.processors.batchProcess
args:
name: ${"projects/" + project_id + "/locations/" + location + "/processors/" + processor_id}
location: ${location}
body:
inputDocuments:
gcsPrefix:
gcsUriPrefix: ${input_gcs_bucket}
documentOutputConfig:
gcsOutputConfig:
gcsUri: ${output_gcs_bucket}
skipHumanReview: true
result: batch_process_resp
- return:
return: ${batch_process_resp}
How can I edit it to prevent it from creating a dynamic folder, if that's not possible, how can I make my streamlit app have access to it to be able to extract details from the json.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
